# How to add a node tree and a Object Separate Text in Blender 2.79b

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to follow this tutorial [Animation Nodes Letter Wiggle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AepOux5G0kQ)
There is created a node tree at minute 2:10 an after that it's added an Text Object Separate, but in the version that I have I can't find how to do that, because I don't know how to add the node tree and also the Add menu is different. Have I to install something? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to blender SE. Animation Nodes is an addon that doesn't come with blender by default, so you need to download and install it first. Please check the [installation guide](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/install/install.html).

Comment: Thank you Omar, I also have to use the version 2.77a instead of 2.79b, it seems that it doesn't work with the latest version.

Comment: @user153489 It is likely that it doesn't work because you are using a version with python 3.5, try downloading a version with python 3.6 from the [release page](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/tag/v2.1_testbuilds_2).